# Html geolocation in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I am trying to use html geolocation in angularjs. I created 2 variables $scope.latitude and $scope.longitude. I then use $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition function (to get the position of the current user), and in there i'm trying to update the 2 variables created before. The problem is, these 2 variables ($scope.latitude and $scope.longitude) are never updated. When i try to get the value of $scope.latitude and $scope.longitude in the variable $scope.map, i'm getting 0 and not their updated values. Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong?. Many thanks

```
var app = angular.module('ihmApp');
app.controller('ContactAmbulanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.latitude = "0";
    $scope.longitude = "0";
$window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.latitude = lat;
        $scope.longitude = lng;
    });
});
$scope.map = { center: { latitude: $scope.latitude, longitude: $scope.longitude }, zoom: 8 };
```

Comment: Most likely a reference problem. Try setting the `$scope.map` within the `$scope.$apply` call

Comment: `geolocation` is asynchronous...can't use the data until it is received

Answer (score 0):

i finally use ngStorage (more details here https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage). i store the value of the 2 variables with ngStorage like this

```
$localStorage.latitude = lat;
$localStorage.longitude = lng;
```